# Accessing currently logged in user ID in Zend framework PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have a .PHTML file and I need to access the currently logged user ID in JS part of the .PHTML file. What are possible ways to do this please???

P.S. I tried storing the ID in the controller part like this:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

and then tried to access it from JS (.PHTML file) like this:

```
console.log(//< ? = $_Session['id'] ? > );
```

But I get absolutely BIG NOTHING. Can someone help me out please?? :/

Comment: You have a comment before the value, and it may need to be in quotes if `id` isn't a numeric value. Try this: `console.log('<?= $_SESSION['id'] ?>');`

Comment: Hi Rory, no it's not that... I added the comment lines accidentally here.. The issue is that I don't have the ID stored in session AT ALL ... I'm literally going nuts here...

Comment: you need "user ID" or "session ID" ?

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case where are you setting `$id` and what's its value?

Comment: and what is the version of ZF ?

Comment: Roman I need user id........

Comment: It is 2.4.7 if I'm correct...

Comment: Try using a `var_dump($_SESSION)` instead.

Comment: it works hehe , ty  so much :)